Change Synology DS418play HDDs or add another Synology NAS to network?
I currently have a Synology DS418play from Synology with four 4TB HDDs for which I currently am using for some file storage, Media Storage (MP4 and MKV files) that I use Plex Media Server to stream to my AppleTV and computers, and as a destination for Carbon Copy Cloner and Apple Time Machine backups of two laptops (I allocated a quota of 4TB for these).
As I am getting close to allocation of total capacity of the storage, I am not sure what to do next.
Do I replace the existing 4TB HDDs with new ones or should I get another machine either the DS423+ or DS923+ and split the tasks between the two devices?
I am in the process of ripping my DVDs and BluRays so that I do not have to have a BluRay player hooked up to my TV all the time and can stream it to any TV in my home. The current 418play does seem to choke while transcoding the MKV files.
If, the recommendation is to replace the 4TB drives with a higher capacity, what do you do with the old drives that are still serviceable and working?
If I add a second NAS to the network, could they be linked so that they use the same username and passwords? Could I move Plex from the 418play to the new device?

there is a lot in that question, and a lot of different ways to go based on your needs and means. provide more info if you would like more appropriate recommendations. Since you do appear to be willing to spend on a new NAS and disks for it, I'd probably get a new Plus model (like the ones you mentioned) as they have more full featured CPUs and will better support the plex server or VMs or docker containers, etc. gmove your workload to the new NAS, and after you have migrated all the data, use the play model with its disks for backups.

What I want to do is have collections of documents (ie Tax, Financial and Medical) that I could have access to at home and in the go. While also having my media available for streaming and viewing.
I am confused as to what would be the better machine for the transcoding and operation of Plex and similar tools.
Does the 923+ support transcoding via hardware? I have seen mixed info. Which is what is confusing me when deciding between the 423 and 923

A lot depends on what you can afford to pay.
